# Prevent PHP DOMDocument from removing @click attributes

Tags: php, domdocument

I have an HTML code where there are attributes like `@click`, `@autocomplete:change` used by some JS libraries.

When I parse the HTML using DOMDocument, these attributes are removed.

Sample code:

```php
<?php

$content = <<<'EOT'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a role="tab" @click="activeType=listingType"></a>
        <input type="text" @autocomplete:change="handleAutocomplete">
    </body>
</html>
EOT;

// creating new document
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;

//turning off some errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// it loads the content without adding enclosing html/body tags and also the doctype declaration
$doc->LoadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a role="tab"></a>
        <input type="text">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems DOMDocument will exclude non-standard attributes, and suppressing warnings won't stop from doing so. You are probably off using a 3rd party parsing engine.

Comment: Are you using DOMDocument to try to clean up bad HTML?

Comment: @kmoser that's right. However I found't any other parsing that's as fast DOMDocument and consumes less resources.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland no, to parse HTML

Comment: But why do you need to parse that HTML?

Comment: @Olivier it's a speed optimization solution for WordPress. Manipulates HTML is different ways

Comment: And I suppose you don't want to recompile the php environment to omit the xmlValidateName check in dom/attr.c

Comment: @ChrisStrickland this code will be deployed to different hosting providers of my clients. So I don't have access to their server to recompile.

Comment: I looked at the sourcecode of libxml, it checks if attribute starts with letters, `_`, and `:`... and fails otherwise :(

Comment: @SalmanA Can you point me to the source code that check?

Comment: Unfortunately attribute names starting with an @ character are [allowed by the HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#syntax-attribute-name). Which makes DOMDocument a bad fit for your problem, because it relies on libxml which [is not a formal HTML5 parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1333730). You might want to have a look at [other parsers](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php) before you start to build more hacks.

Comment: @Code4R7 the other parsers you pointed also uses DOMDocument. Unfortunately there aren't good parsers in PHP that are fast and reliable.

Answer (score 4):

If there's no way to make `DOMDocument` accept `@` in attribute names, we can replace `@` with a special string before `loadHTML()`, and replace back after `saveHTML()`

```php
<?php

$content = <<<'EOT'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a role="tab" @click="activeType=listingType"></a>
        <input type="text" @autocomplete:change="handleAutocomplete">
    </body>
</html>
EOT;

// creating new document
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;

//turning off some errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$content = str_replace('@', 'at------', $content);
// it loads the content without adding enclosing html/body tags and also the doctype declaration
$doc->LoadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$html = $doc->saveHTML();
$html = str_replace('at------', '@', $html);
echo $html;
```

output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a role="tab" @click="activeType=listingType"></a>
        <input type="text" @autocomplete:change="handleAutocomplete">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice, but I don't think you can actually use getAttribute on @click, for instance so if he's trying to parse the value out I don't think this will work.

Comment: This will fail if the HTML already contains instances of "at------" (e.g. as node text) because they will inadvertently get replaced with "@". Better would be to determine a string that is not present in the document, and use that as a sentinel value.

Comment: This is only "hacky" solution I found :|

Answer (score 3):

### Extend the DomDocument class

And replace `@click` with `at-click` and `@autocomplete` with `at-autocomplete`.

```php
# this is a PHP 8 example 
class MyDomDocument extends DomDocument 
{
    private $replace = [
        '@click'=>'at-click',
        '@autocomplete'=>'at-autocomplete'
    ];

    public function loadHTML(string $content, int $options = 0)
    {
        $content = str_replace(array_keys($this->replace), array_values($this->replace), $content);
        return parent::loadHTML($content, $options);
    }

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function saveHTML(?DOMNode $node = null)
    {
        $content = parent::saveHTML($node);
        $content = str_replace(array_values($this->replace), array_keys($this->replace), $content);
        return $content;
    }
}
```

### Example

```php
$content = <<<'EOT'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a role="tab" @click="activeType=listingType"></a>
        <input type="text" @autocomplete:change="handleAutocomplete">
    </body>
</html>
EOT;

$dom = new MyDomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName('a')[0]->getAttribute('at-click'));
var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName('input')[0]->getAttribute('at-autocomplete:change'));

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

### Output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a role="tab" @click="activeType=listingType"></a>
        <input type="text" @autocomplete:change="handleAutocomplete">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use this solution as DOMDocument is used in an internal library.